# How does Objection.js query builders know when a chained call is supposed to be executed?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

As from the example from the [docs](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/query-examples.html#examples)

`await User.query()` returns a promise with an array of users.

`await User.query().findById(1)` returns a user with the ID of 1.

How does the `User.query()` know when a it needs to be executed or if it is chained.

I would assume that once `User.query()` is called, the request is already transmitted to the database server and thus cannot be modified. However, chaining it with `.findById(1)` modifies the request so that it builds the query with a condition where `User.id = 1;` and then transmits it to the DB server?. How does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User.query()` returns a query builder, where one can add as many more chained method calls as one likes:

```
query = User.query();
query.where('id', 1);
query.limit(1);

// also each method returns `this` as return value so chaining is possible

query.select('id', 'name').where('name', 'like', '%batman%')
```

Now that the query is complete and you like to execute the query builder and send query to the database you need to call `.then()` or for example resolve it with `Promise.resolve(query)` which implicitly calls query builder's `.then` method.

In your case you are using `await` to trigger the query which is effectively just syntactic sugar for ´Promise.resolve`

All following examples of executing the query are pretty much equivalent

```
// await with parenthesis underlining execution order of statements
res = await (User.query().select('name'));

// await without parenthesis with implicit execution order
res = await User.query().select('name');

// older way with thenables and promises
User.query().select('name').then(res => {
})

// another way with themables and promises
Promise.resolve(User.query().select('name')).then(res => {

})
```

So all of cases above calls `.then` method of the query builder to execute the query and `.then` returns a promise, which will resolve with the results read from DB.